# Qué debo utilizar en esta oración?

Tags: gramática, pretérito, pretérito-perfecto

> "En dos ocasiones ha sido nominado al Oscar"
>
> "En dos ocasiones fue nominado al Oscar"

Para mí la segunda oración es gramaticalmente correcta porque "las dos ocasiones" han terminado ya, pero si había "en muchas ocasiones", el pretérito perfecto es más correcto.

Pero mi amiga dice que la primera oración es la correcta. ¿Qué decís vosotros?

Comment: Para mi las dos son correctas, aunque mi elección natural sería la primera

Comment: Correctas son las dos. Depende mucho también de la zona geográfica,(en el norte de España se usan más las formas verbales simples) y del tiempo que ha pasado desde entonces. Pero, las dos son correctas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "Katherine Hepburn fue nominada al Oscar en doce ocasiones"

Katherine Hepburn ya murió, así que no puede ser nominada más veces.

> "Hillary Swank ha sido nominada al Oscar en dos ocasiones"

Hillary Swank está aún viva (long live Hillary!), por lo que aún puede ser nominada más veces.

Como ves en los ejemplos, la clave aquí está en si aún puede producirse en más ocasiones o no. Si alguien ya no tiene opción de ser nominado otra vez, entonces es correcto decir "fue nominada"; si aún puede, di "ha sido nominada".

Answer (score 5):

La diferencia entre "fue" y "ha sido" siempre es relativa al periodo de tiempo al que te refieras. Por ejemplo, si nos referimos a este año será "ha sido", porque este año no ha concluido. Si nos referimos al año pasado deberíamos decir "fue", porque el año pasado sí ha concluido. Lo mismo para esta semana (ha hecho buen tiempo) o la semana pasada (hizo buen tiempo), ya que la semana pasada ya ha concluido y esta semana aún no.

Por lo tanto, en tu frase falta saber sobre qué periodo de tiempo estás hablando, eso es lo importante, no el número de veces que ha sido nominado. Si te refieres a que ha sido nominada en esta década, por ejemplo, será "ha sido nominada", y si es en la década pasada "fue nominada". Si te refieres a lo largo de su carrera, dependerá de si ésta entiendes que ha concluido o no.

Answer (score 3):

La diferencia entre "fue" y "ha sido" es la siguiente:

- "fue" (pretérito perfecto simple): Expresa una acción pasada y terminada o concluída, alejada del presente.

  > Ejemplo: Fue interesante su discurso
- "ha sido" (pretérito perfecto compuesto): Expresa una acción pasada pero relacionada con el presente es decir algo que pasó hace muy poco.

  > Ejemplo: Ha sido intensa la lluvia de esta madrugada.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende del marco temporal que el hablante tenga en mente.

En algunos casos queda claro que estamos hablando de alguna acción finalizada por el contexto o por lógica pero muchas veces se escribe de una forma u otra según las costumbres locales o según las preferencias de quien habla.

Por ejemplo en Valencia suele evitarse el uso del préterito perfecto simple por influencia de otra de las lenguas regionales.